# Bind json value to two object in spring MVC restful

Tags: spring, rest, model-view-controller

At present what I have is one view in HTML for entering Person's details and Company's details. I am using spring MVC framework restful.

I create json and send request using Ajax to Restcontroller.based on URL pattern create method is called .e.g. json is

```
{"name":"rohit","address":"Pune","company":"ABC"}
```

Here above name and address belong to person bean and company belongs to company bean. I want the json value bind to their respective bean. How to do it? I have tried the code below but I know it won't work.

```
@Requestmapping(value="/createperson",method=method.post)
public @Responsebody String createperson(@Requestbody person,@Requestbody company)
{

//Some code to save
}
```

I have a form, which will input the person's details and the person's company details.

What I want is that when this form is submitted, some of its fields are bound to Person object properties and some to Company object properties. How can this be done? And how to do validation for json value and send all errors as json responsive again back if there are any errors.

Comment: Can you please put sample code and explanation for error validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one @RequestBody. Spring then looks at the content-type header and finds an appropriate HttpMessageConverter which will read the entire http entity body (input stream) into a single object.

What you have basically done is try to merge Person and company into a single JSON object, and thereby flattened the structure. If you want spring to handle that, you need to create a new object with the same (flat) hierarchy. Or you need to create a wrapper class PersonAndCompany which contains both a Person and a Company, and then change the JSON to match the structure, so it looks like this.

```
{
    "person" : {
        "name":"rohit",
        "address":"Pune"
    },
    "company" : {
        "name":"ABC"
    }
}
```

Comment: OK thanks  and how to send all validation errors again back.how to perform validation in controller.how to bind all errors in response json.

Comment: You can still use the Valid annotation, and property or class validators as anywhere else. However if you send JSON that can't be parsed into the expected input object, you will get a HttpMessageConversionException, You can handle the exception locally in the controller by creating a method with the  ExceptionHandler annotation, or globally across all controllers by using a ControllerAdvice.

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this if you are using relationship between Person and Company otherwise it is better to use single bean instead of two.

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/createperson",  method=RequestMethod.POST ,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Person> createperson(@RequestBody Person person) {

        if(error found ){
            Person p new Person();
            p.setError(" error message ");
            return new ResponseEntity<Person>(p,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Person>(person,HttpStatus.OK);

    }


    public class Person {
        private String name;
        private String address;
        Company company;
        String error;

        --- setters getters 
    }

    public class Company {
        String compName;
        --- setters getters 
    }

input json 
{"name":"person name ","address":"person address ","company":{"compName":"company name"}}
```